# How to make a simple Waffle chart with Actual and Target colors in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite

How to make a simple waffle chart with actual and target colors in vega-lite?
I want a different color for actual and target.
If actual exceeds target then target should not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this. Inspired by Davide Bacci's great work.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "datasets": {"source": [{"Target": "65", "Actual": "45"}]},
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "sequence(1,101)", "as": "Sequence"},
    {"flatten": ["Sequence"]},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Sequence <= datum.Actual ? 'A' : (datum.Sequence <= datum.Target ? 'B' : 'C')",
      "as": "Plot"
    },
    {"calculate": "ceil (datum.Sequence / 10)", "as": "row"},
    {"calculate": "datum.Sequence - datum.row * 10", "as": "col"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "circle",
        "filled": true,
        "tooltip": true,
        "stroke": "#9e9b9b",
        "strokeWidth": 0.7
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "col", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
        "y": {"field": "row", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null, "sort": "-y"},
        "color": {
          "field": "Plot",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": null,
          "condition": [
            {"test": "datum.Plot === 'A'", "value": "#27AE60"},
            {"test": "datum.Plot === 'B'", "value": "#F4D03F"},
            {"test": "datum.Plot === 'C'", "value": "#E5E7E9"}
          ]
        },
        "size": {"value": 241},
        "tooltip": [{"field": "Plot", "type": "nominal", "title": "Status"}]
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 12},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"value": -15},
        "text": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.Sequence == 1",
            "value": {
              "expr": "'Target: ' + datum.Target + '%' + '   ' + 'Actual: ' + datum.Actual + '%'"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}
```

Here is a square version also. The square version is great if you want set a different width and height.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "datasets": {"source": [{"Target": "65", "Actual": "45"}]},
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "sequence(1,101)", "as": "Sequence"},
    {"flatten": ["Sequence"]},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Sequence <= datum.Actual ? 'Completed' : (datum.Sequence <= datum.Target ? 'Target' : 'Remaining')",
      "as": "Plot"
    },
    {"calculate": "ceil (datum.Sequence / 10)", "as": "row"},
    {"calculate": "datum.Sequence - datum.row * 10", "as": "col"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rect",
        "filled": true,
        "tooltip": true,
        "stroke": "#fff",
        "strokeWidth": 1
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "col", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
        "y": {"field": "row", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null, "sort": "-y"},
        "color": {
          "field": "Plot",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": null,
          "condition": [
            {"test": "datum.Plot === 'Completed'", "value": "#27AE60"},
            {"test": "datum.Plot === 'Target'", "value": "#F4D03F"},
            {"test": "datum.Plot === 'Remaining'", "value": "#E5E7E9"}
          ]
        },
        "tooltip": [{"field": "Plot", "type": "nominal", "title": "Status"}]
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 12},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"value": -15},
        "text": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.Sequence == 1",
            "value": {
              "expr": "'Target: ' + datum.Target + '%' + '  ' + 'Actual: ' + datum.Actual + '%'"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}, "background": "#fff"}
}
```

Comment: Do you still need an answer? Should this be part of the question? Is this Deneb or straight VL?

Comment: Stright VL. No I was designing this for a client and wanted to share a very simple version of the waffle chart with only 2 data points: actual vs target. Thanks for asking.